# Debian package creation error

Tags: linux, debian, packaging, dpkg

I'm trying to build a Debian package, but I've got this weird pseudo-directory problem.  I run:

```
$ fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

I've built the binary before, but something must have changed on my system. Now dh_md5sums errors out and returns:

```
md5sum: include: Is a directory
dh_md5sums: command returned error code
make: *** [binary-arch] Error 1
```

Indeed, `include` is a directory.  So, I added some debugging statements to dh_md5sums, to figure out why `include` was being hashed despite the line that was supposed to filter out directories.  Adding:

```
doit("ls", "-l", "$tmp");
```

shows that, indeed, `include` is not a directory when dh_md5sums is run:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 bin
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 var
# some directories removed for brevity's sake
```

So, can I remove it?  I added:

```
doit("rm", "$tmp/include");
```

and got:

```
rm: cannot remove `debian/myproject/include': Is a directory
```

maybe it... turned into a directory?  I added another `ls -l` below the `rm` and got:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 bin
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 var
```

and when the scripts are done running, I can do:

```
$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 x x 4096 2009-06-18 13:48 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 x x 4096 2009-06-18 13:48 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 x x 4096 2009-06-18 13:48 var
```

...which is weird, as `include` becomes a directory and the ownership changes (`x` is my username).  `include` even contains all the header files it's supposed to.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 bin
-rwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 include
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 2009-06-18 13:36 var
# some directories removed for brevity's sake
```

Note that `include` has a link count of 3, indicating that it's either a directory with 1 subdirectory, or a file with 3 hard links. The former seems more likely.

This seems like a bad interaction with fakeroot. I've seen it before where fakeroot sometimes "forgets" permissions, so double check that when `include` is being created or modified that it has the right type (and that none of these have recent changes).